# preg_match_all issue

Tags: php, html, preg-match-all

i am fighting with this small php issue, i am trying to read the url parts from a page.

php code is this:

```
preg_match_all('!<a href="Jobbörse-reader\/items\/(.*?)" title=".+">(.*?)</a>!',$content,$ergebnisse);
```

my problem is that `preg_match_all()` is returning 0 and if i `var_dump` the `$ergebnisse`, i am getting empty array like this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(0) { } }
```

the page code where i am reading from is this:

```
<a href="Jobbörse-reader/items/somelink.html" title="some text">NAME</a>
```

i need somelink.html and NAME, but obviously, it cannot match them, can someone help me please?

BTW: i am reading the content successfully. 
thanks

Comment: What encoding is your content and code in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code

```
<?php
$content='<body>
<a href="Jobbörse-reader/items/somelink.html" title="some text">NAME</a>
</body>';
echo preg_match_all('!<a href="Jobbörse-reader\/items\/(.*?)" title=".+">(.*?)</a>!',$content,$ergebnisse);
echo "\n";
var_dump($ergebnisse);
```

And it totally works:

```
$ php test.php 
1
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(73) "<a href="Jobbörse-reader/items/somelink.html" title="some text">NAME</a>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "somelink.html"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "NAME"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine:

```
   <?php $content='<a href="Jobbörse-reader/items/somelink1.html" title="some text1">NAME1</a>

    <a href="Jobbörse-reader/items/somelink2.html" title="some text2">NAME2</a>

    <a href="Jobbörse-reader/items/somelink3.html" title="some text3">NAME3</a>';

    preg_match_all('!<a href="Jobbörse-reader\/items\/(.*?)" title=".+">(.*?)</a>!',$content,$ergebnisse);

    print_r($ergebnisse);
```

Comment: Copy paste and try. Weird of course because I just copy pasted yours. :D